# Xamarin Forms Custom Control BindableProperty propertyChanged not Firing

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, controls

Trying to set up a very simple custom control to handle alignment when using bullet points in a label. The issue is, the Spans passed into the custom control are not being recognized and the content isn't getting rendered (and the propertyChanged function isn't firing). What am I missing?

XAML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<ContentView
    x:Class="Sample.Controls.BulletPointItem"
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <ContentView.Content>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="10" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Label x:Name="BulletPoint" Text="&#x2022;" />
            <Label x:Name="LabelContent" Grid.Column="1" />
        </Grid>
    </ContentView.Content>
</ContentView>
```

Code-behind:

```
[ContentProperty(nameof(Spans))]
public partial class BulletPointItem : ContentView
{
    // todo add bindable props for bullet point size and color, or even which character to use as the bullet point!
    public static readonly BindableProperty SpansProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(
            nameof(Spans),
            typeof(ObservableCollection<Span>),
            typeof(BulletPointItem),
            new ObservableCollection<Span>(),
            BindingMode.OneWay,
            propertyChanged: OnSpansChanged);

    public BulletPointItem()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Span> Spans
    {
        get => (ObservableCollection<Span>)GetValue(SpansProperty);
        set => SetValue(SpansProperty, value);
    }

    private static void OnSpansChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        var control = (BulletPointItem)bindable;
        var newSpansValue = (ObservableCollection<Span>)newValue;
        var formattedString = new FormattedString();

        if (control == null)
            return;

        if (newSpansValue == null || newSpansValue.Count == 0)
        {
            control.LabelContent.FormattedText = formattedString;
            return;
        }

        foreach (var span in newSpansValue)
        {
            formattedString.Spans.Add(span);
        }

        control.LabelContent.FormattedText = formattedString;
    }
}
```

Attempted Usage:

```
                            <controls:BulletPointItem>
                                <Span Text="Span 1." />
                                <Span FontAttributes="Italic" Text="Span 2." />
                            </controls:BulletPointItem>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Cause:**
**Spans** is an **ObservableCollection**. So if you want to  set the value of it , you should define a Collection in xaml instead of list the Span directly .

Solution:

I still suggest that you should use data-binding since you have set it as a **BindableProperty** .

```
<controls:BulletPointItem BackgroundColor="LightBlue" Spans="{Binding Spans}">
```

#### And in code behind or ViewModel

```
public static readonly BindableProperty SpansProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(
        nameof(Spans),
        typeof(ObservableCollection<Span>),
        typeof(BulletPointItem),
        defaultValueCreator: bindable => new ObservableCollection<Span>(),
        propertyChanged: OnSpansChanged);
```

```
public ObservableCollection<Span> spans { get; set; }
```

```
spans = new ObservableCollection<Span>() {

      new Span(){Text="Span1" },
      new Span(){Text="Span2",FontAttributes=FontAttributes.Italic }
};
```

This will be more flexible when you want to add or remove the items from it .

### Update

When you set the Spans purely from XAML .It will add items to the **Spans**.But the method **OnSpansChanged** will only been invoked when you set it a new value .
So you can handle the logic in method **CollectionChanged** .It will been called each time you add a new item to Spans.

```
public BulletPointItem()
{
  InitializeComponent();
 
  Spans.CollectionChanged += Spans_CollectionChanged;
}

// this method will been invoked 2 times if you add two span in xaml
private void Spans_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
   var collection = sender as ObservableCollection<Span>;
  //...  
}
```

Comment: Hey Lucas, thank you. This does indeed work, but how can I set the Spans purely from XAML? And yes I like the option of binding them but want it to work in the static sense too (purely from XAML).

Comment: Hey Lucas, yep, that was definitely the big thing I was missing... was too tired to comprehend. That, and I was setting a default value (but I should have been using the *DefaultValueCreator*  to create a new ObservableCollection per instance of BulletPointItem, because  by setting the DefaultValue, it just creates a single instance which would be shared between all BulletPointItems. I updated that as well and now I'm good to go. I'd say include this tidbit in your answer for others to see and I will mark it as accepted: defaultValueCreator: bindable => new ObservableCollection<Span>() Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! I have improve my answer and you can accept it now. If you think my answer should been improved , you can directly edit it :)